# How to check if the swap partition is being used correctly in ubuntu 15.10

Tags: partitioning, swap, fstab

when I throw the command 'sudo swapon -s' no error or nothing shows up. I resized my primary partition and deleted my swap and reacreated it updating the values in the fstab file.......I would like to know how to verify if the swap partition is being used. I'm in Ubuntu 15.10. Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23072/how-can-i-check-if-swap-is-active-from-the-command-line/537054

Answer (score 0):

You ask Ubuntu Linux like this:

> swapon -s

Then it displays (for me):

> Filename  Type        Size    Used    Priority
>
> /dev/sda1   partition 8388604 14056   -1

Here you can see where howmuch usage priority.

Do try the help with commands:  command --help

> swapon --help
> In linux just an H might mean Human readable or something else, or try the man pages!

Comment: as I stated above there's no output for that command. The command works but it doesn't display anything even if I execute it with sudo

Comment: what do's top say?

Answer (score 0):

`swapon -s` is deprecated newer Version is

```
swapon --show
```

The above command shows output in well structured format

```
NAME      TYPE      SIZE   USED PRIO
/dev/sda9 partition 7.6G 491.9M   -1
```